# Saving NSUserDefaults Issue?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsuserdefaults

i have been working on a app, and needed to store a string. I used this code to set the default:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setValue:CertificateKey.stringValue forKey:@"SavedKey"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
NSLog(@"%@",[defaults objectForKey:@"SavedKey"]);
```

I loged it, so i know it saved...well, it showed me the value. 
When i open my application, I use this to retrieve the default:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[CertificateKey setStringValue:[defaults objectForKey:@"SavedKey"]];
[CertificateKey setTitleWithMnemonic:[defaults objectForKey:@"SavedKey"]];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Why will it not get the default value? Did i not completely save it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't quit the application by pressing the stop button in xcode. Instead, quit it by right clicking on the application icon and selecting "Quit".

**Edit**

Maybe the first time that you execute the application, you want to save some defaults but you don't want to set them the second+ time that the application runs.

For this purpose in some class initialize method register the defaults, like this:

```
+ (void) initialize
{
    NSUserDefaults* defaults= [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults registerDefaults: @{} ];
    // This case it's an empty dictionary, but you can put whatever you want inside it.
    // just convert it to data if it's not an object storable to a plist file.
}
```

Also, you're using setValue:forKey: , that method is inherited from NSObject. Use setObject:forKey: .

And use finalize if you want to save the defaults at the end:

```
- (void) finalize
{
    // Save the defaults here
}
```

Comment: OK, how do i re-open it without resetting the values?

Comment: No, i already have them set. So, i do not ned to register them

Comment: Try setObject:forKey: instead of setValue:forKey: .

Comment: hey, i just noticed...my onLoad method is not working...i tried your method..and it worked, somewhat. When i add my code in it, to set the values, i get an error. What is that, and how would i do an onload method?

Comment: I need more details. If it's not a big project, may I see it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23426/discussion-between-elite-gamer-and-ramy-al-zuhouri)

Answer (score -1):

You might have a problem because you are creating an instance of NSUserDefaults. From what I understand you are supposed to access it like so: `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"Pikachu" forKey:@"Best Pokemon Ever"]; [[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] objectForKey:@"Best Pokemon Ever"];`  Rather than actually creating an instance of it.

Comment: What I meant was that creating an an instance like so: NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; could be a problem.

Comment: No, this does not cause any problems.

Comment: More generally, [[x y] z] is the same as a = [x y]; [a z]; In *both* cases, no new NSUserDefaults instance is created. The only difference is that a temporary pointer to the shared instance is named in one case, and used without being named in the other case.